# How to remove tracking pixel from SendGrid emails? (Azure context)

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I'm using Azure websites and they offer email services vie the third party provider SendGrid.

It works fine so far but they put a tracking pixel in the emails in order to provide statistics. Some email clients (like Thunderbird) shows a warning message for a remote content in the email.

I want to provide safe to the maximum service for my users and want to remove this tracking pixel from the email. However I cannot find such an option in the settings.

I don't want third party content in my emails. Do you know how to remove it?

(I'm using free SendGrid plan)

Alternatively, does Azure have own SMTP service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per https://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/open_tracking.html

Settings may be changed through:

[SMTP API (on a per message basis)](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html#opentrack)

[Web API (on an account wide basis)](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/filter_settings.html#-Open-Tracking)

Web Interface (on an account wide basis) // have to log into account

You didn't say exactly how you we're implementing it, so it has links to a few different ways. Sounds like it would be easier to log into your account and disable it there.

EDIT:

updated answer from comments

go to [sendgrid.com/app](https://sendgrid.com/app) and its one of the three options there. with a big red disable button on it when you hover over it.

Comment: I haven't implemented it in any way. Neither from the account settings, nor in the code. It seems it is added by default.

Comment: Yeah it is, but you can disable it per message or per account so it's easily enough rectified.  I don't disable it because I like to know the statistics of how many of my emails are being read etc.

Comment: It may be as easy as a click to disable it globally. However, I cannot find this option on their web interface: http://s7.postimg.org/gxoz9gfp7/screenshot_467.png

Comment: Or I have to make a POST request to switch on/off options?

Comment: I just went to https://sendgrid.com/app and it was one of the three options there.  with a big red disable button on it when you hover over it.

Comment: This was the exact solution. Can you make it an answer in order to close the question.